# Changing head from page with jquery

Tags: jquery

With Jquery I dynamically change the head of my page I do that like this:

```
$(document).attr("title", $('pile').text());
```

This is working and I see the that the head changes. But when I look in my page source it's not changed. Why is that, and how can I change that as wel?

I've to do this so the site can be better found on google.

Comment: Don't use page source to look for dom changes.  Use the Element Inspector instead (right click, Inspect Element).

Comment: Thanks that dit the trick!

Comment: page source is a static representation of what was downloaded from the server. It doesn't change and it's not intended to. Use your browser's developer tools to inspect the current state of the DOM.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is looking at wrong thing and code works

Comment: Side note, it's unnecessary to make a jQuery object of the document and then use the attr() method.  Just do `document.title = $('pile').text()`.  `attr()` is useful if you already have a jQuery object and you want to change something's attribute.  But if you start off with the dom element, there's no reason to add that additional overhead.